# NodeJS sending index.js file as response

Tags: node.js, plesk, production

So i built an app using NodeJS in the backend and ReactJs in the frontend and everything worked well while testing. Now everytime i make a request in the production server, the request sends the index.html content instead of the data.

Here is the content of server.js

```
//Some imports

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit: "100mb",
    parameterLimit: 1000000,
  })
);
const port = 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.set("trust proxy", true);

...

app.post('/api/test', async (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world!")
});
```

//Sample of the nodejs response
[image]

//Sample of a function that makes a request
[image]

```
//This belongs to the call function that checks for the validity of the token!

        //Main Request
        await api.post(EndPoint, BodyObject, { headers: headers })
            .then(async function (response) {

                //A resposta da main pode ser 2 coisas
                //--A resposta do request com a data
                //--A resposta do /api/auth com a mensagem a dizer que o token está invalido  

                //Unsuccessful request
                if (response.data == "Access Token expired" || response.data == "There's something wrong with token") {
                    //Store invalid to call /newToken endPoint
                    tokenValidity = false;
                    //Unsuccessful request
                } else if (response.data == "Invalid Signature") {
                    //Redirect to Login
                    window.location.href = "https://www.link.pt/login";
                }
                //Successful request
                else {
                    serverResponse = response.data;
                }
            })
```

//Sample of an endpoint in server.js
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
```

you're sending the index.html file as response to all routes other than /api/test

Comment: Yes, i forgot that it was there... After removing it, the problem stays the same

Comment: Any idea what else can cause this problem?

Comment: @Fury what is your expected output and how are you making the post request?

Comment: The output is the data received from the DB in the endpoint... In server.js, im doing this (Image in the question)

Comment: Can you add an example of the request that you send from the client to the server that responds with the index.html? Also, can you show us the index.html file that is being served? You said the data you pass from the client to the server responds with the index.html file? I don't understand why it would serve an index.html file anyways. A React.js app is usually a SPA and you don't serve the index.html from the server like you would in vanilla js. This should be all handled for you once you run 'npm run build' on the frontend. More information would be great to help you better.

Comment: The example of a request made is in the question, the index.html is the same when it is created at first... But its content is printed in the console

Answer (score -1):

I need to see the frontend code where you are making the request

Comment: URL has to be "link/api/insertlogsDB" if you need to call that specific api

Comment: It's now in the question!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).